# For loop printing weird numbers while traversing an array?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++. I learned Java before and I found that C++ is very similar in terms of structure.

Here is a 2D array and I traverse it and print all the values to make a 3 by 3 grid of 0's. But it prints out weird numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int board[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

This prints out:

```
0 0 0 
0 -13088 0 
-13168 0 -12816
```

Edit: Thank you! I didn't know that C++ needed initialization. Arrays in Java are stored with 0's by default. Will keep this in mind while learning!

Comment: Uninitialised array contains garbage. Try this: `int board [3][3]{};`

Comment: you din assigned any value to array

Comment: In c++ you have to initialize your variables, if you don't they will contain random values. Try with `int board[3][3]{};`

Comment: " I found that C++ is very similar in terms of structure." -- beware of this line of thought. Java and C++ may have a similar syntax for certain constructs, but they are rather different languages. Some simple code blocks may look exactly the same in both languages, but when you start dealing with (among many others) pointers, memory management, and undefined behavior you realize that the differences are huge.

Comment: Regarding your edit: "_Edit: Thank you! I didn't know that C++ needed initialization. Arrays in Java are stored with 0's by default. Will keep this in mind while learning!_". - That doesn't belong in your question. You can thank people by accepting their answer (if you've gotten a helpful answer). There should be a grayed out checkbox next to the answers you get.

Answer (score 2):

**initialization is missing**

```
int board[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

**output**

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: True, but please note that the OP want "to make a 3 by 3 grid of **0**'s".

Comment: int board[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

Comment: Just a [`{}`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) is enough ;).